Error reproducing an example
I am trying to reproduce the example from this awesome article (link). This is my first code in Metapost and I am getting an error running the following code:
prologues := 3; % set up MetaPost for EPS generation
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.mps";


beginfig(1) % begin figure no. 1


r=5cm;draw fullcircle scaled 2r;

let vector=color;
let Xp=redpart; let Yp=greenpart; let Zp=bluepart;

def dotproduct(expr Vi,Vj)=
(Xp(Vi)*Xp(Vj)+Yp(Vi)*Yp(Vj)+Zp(Vi)*Zp(Vj))
enddef;

def vecproduct(expr Vi,Vj)=
(Yp(Vi)*Zp(Vj)-Zp(Vi)*Yp(Vj),
Zp(Vi)*Xp(Vj)-Xp(Vi)*Zp(Vj),
Xp(Vi)*Yp(Vj)-Yp(Vi)*Xp(Vj))
enddef;

def norm(expr V)= sqrt(dotproduct(V,V)) enddef;
def normed(expr V)= (V/norm(V)) enddef;

%ORIENTATION IN SPACE

vector V[]; % vector array
theta=70;phi=-15;
V1=(cosd theta,sind theta,0);
V2=(sind(phi)*sind(theta),
-sind(phi)*cosd(theta),cosd(phi));
V3=vecproduct(V1,V2);

%THE PROJECTION

def project(expr V,Va,Vb)=
(dotproduct(V,Va),dotproduct(V,Vb))
enddef;
z0=(0,0);
z1=project((r,0,0),V1,V2);
z2=project((0,r,0),V1,V2);
z3=project((0,0,r),V1,V2);
drawarrow z0--z1;drawarrow z0--z2;
drawarrow z0--z3;

%EQUATOR

def f_equ(expr r,t)=(r*cosd(t),r*sind(t),0) enddef;
path equator; equator=
project(f_equ(r,0),V1,V2)
for t=10 step 10 until 350:
.. project(f_equ(r,t),V1,V2)
endfor .. cycle;
%draw equator withcolor blue;

def ellipse(expr ra,rb,an)=
(fullcircle xscaled 2ra yscaled 2rb rotated an)
enddef;
%draw ellipse(r,.5r,0);

%DETERMINATION ELEMENTS ELLIPSE

vardef ellipse_major_angle(expr p,a)=
save pa,pc,pi,ra,rb,rc,an;
path pc[];pair pa,pi[];ra=.5a;rb=a;
forever: %======== dichotomy ==========
rc:=.5[ra,rb];
pc0:=subpath(0,4) of fullcircle scaled 2rc;
pa:=pc0 intersectiontimes p;
exitif pa<>(-1,-1);ra:=rc;
endfor;
%=== computation of two intersections ===
pi1=p intersectiontimes pc0;
pc1=subpath(0,ypart(pi1)-0.01) of pc0;
pc2=subpath(ypart(pi1)+0.01,length(pc0)) of pc0;
pi1:=p intersectionpoint pc0;
pi2:=p intersectiontimes pc1;
if pi2=(-1,-1):
pi2:=p intersectionpoint pc2;
else:
pi2:=p intersectionpoint pc1;
fi;
pi3=pi1 rotated 180;
pi4=pi2 rotated 180; % other intersections
%======= orientation ======
pi5=p intersectionpoint
(origin--(unitvector(pi2-pi1)*2a));
pi6=p intersectionpoint
(origin--(unitvector(pi1-pi4)*2a));
if arclength(origin--pi5)>arclength(origin--pi6):
an=angle(pi1-pi2);
else:
an=angle(pi1-pi4);
fi;
an % result of the macro
enddef;

vardef ellipse_minor_axis(expr p,a,an)=
save pa;pair pa;
pa=p intersectionpoint (origin--(dir(an+90)*2a));
arclength(origin--pa) % result
enddef;

%DASHES EQUATOR

path pa,pb,pc;
pa=ellipse(r,rb,0);
pb=subpath(0,4) of pa;
pc=subpath(4,8) of pa;
draw pb dashed evenly; % hidden
draw pc; % visible

endfig; % end figure

end % end of MetaPost run



(0,0,1,0,0,2rb)
! Transform components aren't all known.

rotated
ellipse->....xscaled2(EXPR0)yscaled2(EXPR1)rotated
(EXPR2))
l.108 pa=ellipse(r,rb,0)


I can see is coming from the rb variable but I can´t see the fix. Any help would be apreciated.

rb is not defined (only locally inside the definition). Either you set it to what you want, or given the commented ellipse draw, do pa=ellipse(r,.5r,0); instead.

@mickep Is this an error in the article, do you think?

@cfr I did not read in all the details, but the problem in OP's code is indeed  that rb is used but not known. Maybe the author of the article did have it set, but it was lost in the article.

@mickep Thanks. I took the code from the article and my conclusion was that it needed to be set somewhere, but wasn't. But my metapost abilities are severely limited, so I did not draw much of a conclusion from my conclusion.

I raised this issue at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65953151#65953151. See https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65953320#65953320 for followup.

Thank you all for your time, I will try to make a working mp file covering all the article to post it and help future users.

@Mac -- I have looked into the source of the article and the log from the production run, and failed to find the string rb except in "orbit". (I haven't, however, tried to rerun it.)  You might try asking the author -- his address is included at the end of the article.  If all else fails, I'll try reprocessing the article after checking with the author.

If you want more metapost-specific help, you could try writing the public mailing list, metapost@tug.org. FWIW.

@barbarabeeton Thank you very much.

The code seems to miss statements for the two macros that determine the elements for ellipse(r,rb,0). For example, add these two
statements in front of path pa,pb,pc; to get working code and the
drawing of section 4.8.
an=ellipse_major_angle(equator,r);
rb=ellipse_minor_axis(equator,r,an);

(Of course, I don't know if that was the original code.)
The author wants to simplify the path of the equator that is built from a lot
of points. To replace this path by the simpler ellipse one
needs to know the minor axis; in the code it is called rb.  The two macros are written
to extract this value from equator.
Now with the new pa one has only to deal with the
points of the fullcircle.
Are you aware of
http://berndt-schwerdtfeger.de/wp-content/uploads/pdf/sphere.pdf ,
whose METAPOST code is available in
http://berndt-schwerdtfeger.de/wp-content/uploads/mp/sphere.mp .
This text gives more background of the mathematics and seems to
have simpler code. He uses a construction called halfell which seems to simplify the coding of split ellipses.
